# Glue Dev Endpoint access Catalog with SparkSession

Tags: aws-glue

I tried setting up a AWS glue dev endpoint to test a very simple ETL script, but I cannot seem to get to my catalog data.

I didn't bother with zeppelin and just used the scala-repl.

spark.catalog.listTables.show -> is Empty.

When I try to create a SparkSession the way I do in my emr steps

```
SparkSession.builder()
              .config("hive.metastore.connect.retries", 5)
              .config("hive.metastore.client.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory")
              .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
              .enableHiveSupport().appName("ETL")
              .getOrCreate()
```

I get this result and no tables.

```
18/07/24 09:08:00 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
18/07/24 09:08:00 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
18/07/24 09:08:01 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
18/07/24 09:08:01 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; some configuration may not take effect
```

What I want to do with this script is actually really simple.
I have a view (create in zeppelin on a spark emr cluster) that has cols like year,month,day,x,y,z and I just want to materialize one day e.g. year(current_timestamp), month..
for one day as parquet and append it to a partitioned table.

If I had some way to insert and overwrite partitions it would be even better, and I was hoping glue simplifies scheduling.
Did I misunderstand glue, does it just not support using standard sparksession sql only scripts.

The data later should be read by athena and more complex spark emr jobs. This seemed like a dead simple etl job for glue (it is SQL only almost) but it does require catalog access and spark[SparkSession].write.mode("append").parquet... to work.